# How do I assign values to a matrix inside a struct?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

I have a header file with this type definition:

```
typedef struct {
    int rows;
    int columns;
    int **values;
} bidimensional_matrix;
```

As an example, If I instantiate the matrix from a main function I'd just do:

```
int matrix[][] = {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 1, 1}, {5, 5, 5}};
```

How would you generate the same matrix but with the typedef provided previously? (I mean, with pointers and malloc)

Is the approach correct? Maybe I'm a little object oriented biased and in c it's not convenient to handle it that way. I've defined the struct that way so I can just pass two `bidimensional_matrix` by parameter and do a multiplication.

Comment: With malloc : `bidimensional_matrix a; a.rows=3; a.columns=3; a.values = malloc(3*3*sizeof(int)); memcpy(a.values, matrix);`

Answer (score 1):

I propose you to use flexible member array, exemple:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    size_t n;
    size_t m;
    int matrix[];
} bidimensional_matrix;

bidimensional_matrix *new_bidimensional_matrix(size_t n, size_t m) {
    bidimensional_matrix *bm = malloc(sizeof *bm + sizeof *bm->matrix * n * m);
    if (!bm) {
        return NULL;
    }
    *bm = (bidimensional_matrix){ .n = n, .m = m };
    return bm;
}

int get_bidimensional_matrix(bidimensional_matrix *bm, size_t i, size_t j) {
    return bm->matrix[i * bm->m + j];
}

int set_bidimensional_matrix(bidimensional_matrix *bm, size_t i, size_t j, int x) {
    return bm->matrix[i * bm->m + j] = x;
}

int main(void) {
    bidimensional_matrix *bm = new_bidimensional_matrix(5, 10);
    if (!bm) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < bm->n * bm->m; i++) {
        bm->matrix[i] = i;
    }
    printf("sample value %d\n", get_bidimensional_matrix(bm, 4, 5));
    set_bidimensional_matrix(bm, 4, 5, 42);
    printf("sample value %d\n", get_bidimensional_matrix(bm, 4, 5));
    free(bm);
}
```

---

But you could use this too, that have other avantage but generally is more slow:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    size_t n;
    size_t m;
    int **matrix;
} bidimensional_matrix;

int main(void) {
    bidimensional_matrix bm = { .n = 5, .m = 10, .matrix = malloc(sizeof *bm.matrix * bm.n) };
    if (!bm.matrix) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < bm.n; i++) {
        bm.matrix[i] = malloc(sizeof *bm.matrix[i] * bm.m);
        if (!bm.matrix[i]) {
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        for (size_t j = 0; j < bm.m; j++) {
            bm.matrix[i][j] = i * bm.m + j;
        }

    }
    printf("sample value %d\n", bm.matrix[4][5]);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < bm.n; i++) {
        free(bm.matrix[i]);
    }
    free(bm.matrix);
}
```

---

If you need to swap rows the second could be a little faster cause swap row are O(1). But like you see the first one has only one `malloc()`, in practice with the cache of the processor it should be a lot more faster than the second implementation.